# How do I bind a WPF control's margin to a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a C#/.Net WPF desktop application.
There are a series of WPF controls defined in which I'd like to change the margins dynamically at runtime.

How do I bind a control's margin to properties in the code behind?

**Consider the following control:**

```
<TextBox Name="Foo" Text="Foo Text"  Margin="0,10,0,10">
```

**I have the following defined in my main window:**

```
public double TopMargin {get; set;}
public double BottomMargin {get; set;}
```

I would like to be able to change the margins dynamically, so that if I change the margin in my runtime C# code, the new margin values get reflected in the UI.

**If it is easier, I would consider using:**

```
public Thickness FooMargin{get; set;}
```

What's the cleanest/best way to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to use like you suggested:

```
 public Thickness TextBoxMargin { get; set; }
```

and then you can create your margin using the left, up, right, down (margin) values that you want in Thickness's constructor

```
 TextBoxMargin = new Thickness(5,5,5,5);
```

If you are using MVVM, you can bind like a regular property from your view model:

```
<TextBox Name="Foo" Text="Foo Text"  Margin="{Binding TextBoxMargin}">
```

If you want to do it in code behind then in your user control's just assign:

```
Foo.Margin = TextBoxMargin;
```

Comment: RS: I'm still running into issues. I get a "BindingExpression path error." It can't find/bind to TextBoxMargin @ runtime.

Comment: RS: I'm still running into issues. I get a "BindingExpression path error." It can't find/bind to TextBoxMargin @ runtime. I'm applying the binding through a <ControlTemplate> in XAML. My XAML code looks like this: <ControlTemplate> <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="{Binding TextBoxMargin}"> <TextBox Text="Foo" Background=/> </StackPanel> </ControlTemplate>

Comment: Need to set DataContext=this in constructor in your code behind.